# How to publish ASMX web service

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services

I have created an asmx web service in visual studio 11. I want to publish that web service.  Does anybody know  free web host server URL ?

Comment: you can use your service in local network if you run on your iis for public domain you need webserver from hosting provider

Comment: Thanks for replies, it seems publishing over the internet using hosting provider more makes sense, since i want everybody to be able to access my service. In this case, I need a free web hosting provider that provides me Service URL as showing picture. Does anybody know it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, just publish to a folder on computer, then upload THAT folder to your ftp, then your service should work.  It has for me many times (including a flash "chat" window i did not long ago).
My hosting is godaddy, but that should have nothing to do with it.